# Consoles and Tabs

Tags: console, cmd, console2

When I start the tomcat server from console using the startup.bat script, a new command window opens which is filled with java logging statements.

I use Console2 which leverages tabs for each open console window. Is it possible to let the java system create a new tab within console2 instead of just opening a new command window?

Comment: Do you want to try another console emulator? I'm an author of ConEmu, and it allows creating tabs from external batches.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with java, its merely down to the way the catalina.bat is called from startup.bat

catalina.bat can be called with either a "start" argument or a "run" argument.

```
run               Start Catalina in the current window
start             Start Catalina in a separate window
```

So open startup.bat, scroll to the bottom you should see

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

change that to

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" run %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
exit
```

I add an exit after to close the calling window.

Answer (score 0):

Unless Console2 hooks any APIs that create console windows – no. And that's also highly unlikely that they do or even can. Console2 does nothing more than hook up input and output of console windows. What the programs in those do is beyond what it's interested in.